Prove the closed form of $\int_0^T \exp\left(\frac{ia}{T-\tau}+\frac{ib}{\tau}\right)\frac{d\tau}{\left[\sqrt{(T-\tau)\tau}\right]^3}$.
While working through the Dover book "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals", I stumbled across a problem requiring me to use the following identity given in the book's appendix.
$$\int_0^T \exp\left(\frac{ia}{T-\tau}+\frac{ib}{\tau}\right)\frac{d\tau}{\left[\sqrt{(T-\tau)\tau}\right]^3} = \sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{T^3}}\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{ab}}\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)^2\right)$$
I've spent around a year trying to either prove this or find an existing proof for it. My question is, how exactly would one go about proving this?

I've tried numerous chains of substitutions, aiming to (among other things) remove the square root with trig substitutions (with initial success in the case of $\tau \rightarrow Tu + \frac{1}{2}T, u \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\cos\theta$, but to limited success thereafter) or convert the problem into an improper integral which may hopefully be evaluated with the help of the Gaussian integral. The latter method has been the most promising so far with the following line of work.
$$
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^T\exp\left(\frac{ia}{T-\tau}+\frac{ib}{\tau}\right)\frac{d\tau}{\left[\sqrt{(T-\tau)\tau}\right]^3} \\
(u = 1/\tau) \quad &\rightarrow \int_\infty^{1/T}\exp\left(\frac{ia}{T-1/u}+\frac{ib}{1/u}\right)\frac{-u^{-2}\cdot du}{\left[\sqrt{(T-1/u)(1/u)}\right]^3} \\
&= \int_{1/T}^\infty\exp\left(iu\left[\frac{a}{uT-1}+b\right]\right)\frac{u\cdot du}{\left[\sqrt{uT-1}\right]^3}\\
(z = uT - 1) \quad &\rightarrow \int_0^\infty\exp\left(i\frac{z+1}{T}\left[\frac{a}{z}+b\right]\right)\frac{z+1}{T}\frac{T^{-1} \cdot dz}{\sqrt{z}^3} \\
&= \frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(i\frac{z+1}{T}\left[\frac{a}{z}+b\right]\right)\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z}^3}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{ia}{T}\left[1 + \frac{1}{z}\right]+\frac{ib}{T}\left[1+z\right]\right)\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z}^3}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{T^2}\exp\left(\frac{i(a+b)}{T}\right)\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\frac{a}{z} + bz\right]\right)\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z}^3}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{T^2}\exp\left(\frac{i(a+b)}{T}\right)\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{z}}-\sqrt{bz}\right)^2 + 2\sqrt{ab}\right]\right)\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z}^3}dz \\
&= \frac{e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2/T}}{T^2}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\sqrt{\frac{a}{z}}-\sqrt{bz}\right]^2\right)\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z}^3}dz \\
(v=\sqrt{z}) \quad &\rightarrow \frac{e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2/T}}{T^2}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{v}-v\sqrt{b}\right]^2\right)\frac{v^2+1}{v^3}\cdot2vdv \\
&= 2\frac{e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2/T}}{T^2}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{v}-v\sqrt{b}\right]^2\right)\frac{v^2+1}{v^2}dv \\
&= \frac{e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2/T}}{T^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{v^2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{v}-v\sqrt{b}\right]^2\right)dv \\
\end{align*}
$$
Here we see the expected exponential term has appeared in the front and the remaining indefinite integral appears to be slightly nicer than the original problem. However, I'm stumped as to how I can evaluate the remaining integral factor.

I also considered a residue theorem approach to the initial integral, though I believe that this would be unlikely to work due to the integrand's non-isolated singularities at $\tau = 0$ and $\tau = T$.

Any proofs (or pointers towards helping me discover one on my own) would be greatly appreciated!

Your computations seem correct; however, you didn't choose the easiest path to handle this problem. Indeed, setting $f_c(t) := t^{-3/2}e^{-c/t}$, we may recast the considered integral as a (truncated) convolution product, as follows :
$$
\int_0^T \frac{e^{ia/(T-\tau)}}{(T-\tau)^{3/2}} \frac{e^{ib/\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}} \mathrm{d}\tau = (f_{c_1}*f_{c_2})(T),
$$
with $c_1 = -ia$ and $c_2 = -ib$. Let's recall that is the convolution product is mapped to the usual product through the Laplace transform. Since the Laplace transform of $f_c$ is given by $F_c(s) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}} e^{\sqrt{-4cs}}$ (see Gradstein & Ryzhik for instance), one has thus :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}[f_{c_1}*f_{c_2}](s) 
   &= F_{c_1}(s)F_{c_2}(s) \\
   &= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{c_1c_2}} e^{\sqrt{-4c_1s}+\sqrt{-4c_2s}} \\
   &= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{c_1c_2}} \exp\left(\sqrt{-4s(\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2})^2}\right) \\
   &= \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2}}{\sqrt{c_1c_2}} F_{(\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2})^2}(s)
\end{align}
$$
As the result displays the same structure, the inverse transform can be deduced straightforwardly, namely $\mathscr{L}^{-1}[F_{(\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2})^2}](T) = f_{(\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2})^2}(T)$, hence the desired result (up to the $-i$ factors) :
$$
\int_0^T \frac{e^{ia/(T-\tau)}}{(T-\tau)^{3/2}} \frac{e^{ib/\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}} \mathrm{d}\tau = \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2}}{\sqrt{c_1c_2}} \frac{e^{-(\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2})^2/T}}{T^{3/2}}
$$

Final remark.
Even if this relation may seem arbitrary at first glance and result from the "luck of computations", it comes from a deeper property actually. Indeed, the function $f_c(t)$ corresponds to the density of a Lévy distribution. Moreover, the convolution of two PDFs or equivalently the product of their characteristic functions can be interpreted as the distribution of their sum. Yet, the Lévy distribution is a stable law, meaning that linear combinations of Lévy-distributed random variables will be Lévy-distributed too (with other parameters, nonetheless), that is why the same structure was preserved through the product of Laplace transforms.

Edit (see comments).
Coming back to the initial parametrization, we get :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \frac{e^{ia/(T-\tau)}}{(T-\tau)^{3/2}} \frac{e^{ib/\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}} \mathrm{d}\tau 
   &= \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{-ia}+\sqrt{-ib}}{\sqrt{-ab}} \frac{e^{-(\sqrt{-ia}+\sqrt{-ib})^2/T}}{T^{3/2}} \\
   &= \sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{-i}{-1}}\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{ab}} \frac{e^{-\left(\sqrt{-i}(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{b})\right)^2/T}}{T^{3/2}} \\
   &= \sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{T^3}} \frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{ab}} \exp\left(\frac{i}{T}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)^2\right)
\end{align}
$$

I absolutely love this answer! I had considered whether the Laplace Transform may be useful in the proof but did not know enough about convolutions to apply a method like this on my own. My only remaining question is how one may go about recovering the missing $i$ factors seeing as they are rather important?

@AnneJones  Thank you :) I've edited my answer in order to show how to get back to the initial parametrization, as you requested.

Awesome! I honestly can't thank you enough for this; this problem has been driving me crazy for a year!

@AnneJones  You're welcome ! Glad to help ;)
